# Regular expression which matches *.string or only string

Tags: c#, regex

I'am little week in regular expressions.

How to match below URLs using C# regular expressions.

1. www.mask3.com
2. mask3.com,
3. *.mask3.com

Comment: what do you mean by `*.`? Did you tried anything?

Comment: Please share what have you tried

Comment: any other rules? if no ,here is `^.*?\.com$`

Comment: is that really a comma in the second url?

Comment: Did you try `[^.]*.?mask3\.com,?`

Comment: I've to match anything which ends with mask3.com, so you can consider mask3.com as static. but it should match  with- [mask3.com] or [*.mask3.com]. Please note that something like [xyzmask3.com] should not be matched.

Comment: @Peeyush you mean this http://regex101.com/r/qE6oS6/4 ?

Comment: Avinash- the regular expression will also match something like- [xyzmask3.com] which i don't want to be matched.

Comment: you can try: `^.*?\bmask3\.com$`  :  http://regex101.com/r/qE6oS6/5

Comment: I don't think Peeyush is looking to find the * literally, that's just his way of explaining he wants the include the subdomain if it's there. Like in DOS you search for `*.bat` to find your batch files, not files which name **actually** contains the asterisk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
`^.*?\bmask3\.com$`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qE6oS6/5):

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"^(?:(?:www|\*)\.)?mask3\.com$")
```

Comment: It will not match something like- xyz.mask3.com

Answer (score 0):

You're giving very little information, do you want to find the text or see if it is the entire text? This finds instances of any website url that is a subdomain of mask3.com.

```
\b(?:\w+\.)?mask3\.com\b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/5KEP5iHCeE1iMd2V)